# How to get recursive aliases in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, alias

I have multiple `aliases` that are aliased to a one common alias due to handle some typos. Please note that I am using `which` in `zsh` shell and `type` in `bash`.

For example:

```
alias netlab="ssh user@IP_ADDRESS"
alias n=netlab
alias ne=netlab
alias net=netlab
alias nn=netlab
```

---

When I try to get type of the alias I get following:

```
$ which -sa n  # in ZSH-shell
n: aliased to netlab

$ type n  # in BASH-shell
n is an alias for netlab
```

---

Since `netlab` has an alias too, can I get that as well? So basically, I want to apply `which program` recursively.

Example output I want:

```
$ type n  # in BASH-shell 
n: aliased to netlab
netlab: aliased to ssh user@IP_ADDRESS
```

or just returning its latest alias:

```
$ type n
n: aliased to ssh user@IP_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Which _bash_ version are you using (you can check it using `echo $BASH_VERSION`)? In mine (4.4), `which` is still an extern command and hence can not show aliases currently defined. I don't know if this feature was incorporated in a later bash versionl.

Comment: loop over alias `x=nn; while alias "$x"  2>/dev/null; do x=$(alias "$x") && x=${x#alias*=\'} && x=${x%\'}; done`, may loop forever `alias a=b; alias b=a;`

Comment: @user1934428 sorry I was able to use `which` in `zsh` shell ; for `bash` I am using `type` . I updated my questions for clearity

Comment: I don't know a built-in way which can show  you how aliases resolve recursively. If you really need this feature, I suggest that you write a function which is doing this. i believe that cases where one alias is defined in terms of an other alias are rare, and perhaps this is the reason, why the language designers did not provide such a command in bash or zsh.

Comment: There could be only one alias for each word. Not sure could we come up with a alias dependency till the bottom level. But as I understand from comments it may inter a endless loop. //But @that other guy 's answer was what I was looking for set that has multiple words that are linked to a single alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use brace expansion to alias multiple names into the same string:

```
alias {netlab,n,ne,net,nn}="ssh user@IP_ADDRESS"
```

Answer (score 1):

The set of aliases are not passed into bash scripts. You could use `source` to access the aliases, then use `type` to loop until the real command is found. I can't imagine running a script using `source` would be convenient.

However, you can use bash scripts and symbolic links to accomplish the same results as your aliases.

The following assumes that $HOME/bin is on your PATH.

cat < $HOME/bin/netlab
ssh user@IP_ADDRESS
EOF

ln -s $HOME/bin/netlab $HOME/bin/n
ln -s $HOME/bin/netlab $HOME/bin/ne
ln -s $HOME/bin/netlab $HOME/bin/net
ln -s $HOME/bin/netlab $HOME/bin/nn

Now using any of the new "aliases" will invoke the original script.